# Kendo numeric format for SQL Server "money" data type

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendonumerictextbox

I'd appreciate any advice.

I use a `NumericTextBox` for the SQL Server datatype `money`:

```
 @Html.Kendo().NumericTextBoxFor(model => model.AMOUNT)
```

It displays the sum incorrectly. Like if the `AMOUNT` is `2000,00` in `NumericTextBox` it is shown as `20,000,000.00`.

How to format it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Format` method:

```
@Html.Kendo().NumericTextBoxFor(model => model.AMOUNT).Format("c");
```

Use any format you want, a [standard one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx) or a custom one. Also do note the culture should be taken into account.

Comment: You were right about culture, added .Culture("en-US"), and it is correct now. Thanks!